# How to use list.replace after a specific character in Python

Tags: python

I have a list in python.

```
MyList = ["ONE APPLE", "TWO PEAR", "THREE APPLE"]
```

I want to replace all the 'E' characters with 'A' characters in the fruit words, but not in the number words. So far I have tried using list.replace, however as far as I can tell indiscriminately replaces all 'E's with 'A's.

The code `list = [list.replace('E', 'A') for list in list]` outputs

```
"ONA APPLA"
"TWO PAAR"
"THRAA APPLA"
```

Whereas I want the following.

```
"ONE APPLA"
"TWO PAAR"
"THREE APPLA"
```

Is there any way of using the replace function after the `' '`, or is another method more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = ["ONE APPLE", "TWO PEAR", "THREE APPLE"]
>>> result = [ ''.join(i.split()[0] + ' '+ i.rsplit()[1].replace('E', 'A')) for i in my_list ]
>>> result
['ONE APPLA', 'TWO PAAR', 'THREE APPLA']

#OR

>>> result = [ '{} {}'.format(i.split()[0], i.rsplit()[1].replace('E', 'A')) for i in my_list ]
>>> result
['ONE APPLA', 'TWO PAAR', 'THREE APPLA']
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. An ideal solution.